# How can we access to 3rd party log files in Heroku

Tags: heroku

In our application hosted in Heroku, we use 3rd party agents for monitoring and profiling purposes. The application writes to the log "a log file is created" for the activity of itself as below.

```
Using heroku as Agent storage
Log file at heroku/log/dt_SampleApp_bootstrap_1.log
```

Is it possible to access these files via Heroku Toolbelt? Heroku logs does not show the content of this file as expected. Also I connected to heroku server via `heroku run bash` but I couldn't find the stated file. It's not under `/app` folder. Do you have any idea where we can find it?

Answer (score 0):

Each heroku dyno has an ephemeral filesystem. This means that you should treat it as read-only.

More info on the file system: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos

You should look into writing any files to another service (such as S3).

What gem are you using that creates logs?

Comment: The application is based on java and the 3rd party library is Dynatrace agent.

Comment: Ahh, I can't assume heroku = ruby any more. :-). Not familiar with Dynatrace. As far as I know, only way to write to heroku logs is System.err.println("write to logs").
I'd look into seeing if Dynatrace can be configured to store log files on S3.